# frontier ethereum pallet integration, the trait `fc_rpc::format::Formatter` is not implemented for `Geth`

Tags: rpc, frontier, ethereum

I'm trying to copy a function from the frontier pallet(fc_rpc::format::Formatter), I copied it to a file and imported that.
frontier-752fb1c28a6c675a/ea37e8f/client/rpc/src/format.rs
It's the same code:

```rust
use pallet_ethereum::TransactionValidationError as VError;
use sc_transaction_pool_api::error::{Error as PError, IntoPoolError};
use sp_runtime::transaction_validity::InvalidTransaction;

pub trait Formatter: Send + Sync + 'static {
    fn pool_error(err: impl IntoPoolError) -> String;
}

// Formatter keeping the same output as before the introduction of this
// formatter design.
pub struct Legacy;

impl Formatter for Legacy {
    fn pool_error(err: impl IntoPoolError) -> String {
        format!("submit transaction to pool failed: {:?}", err)
    }
}

// Formats the same way Geth node formats responses.
pub struct Geth;

impl Formatter for Geth {
    fn pool_error(err: impl IntoPoolError) -> String {
        // Error strings from :
        // https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/794c6133efa2c7e8376d9d141c900ea541790bce/core/error.go
        match err.into_pool_error() {
            Ok(PError::AlreadyImported(_)) => "already known".to_string(),
            // In Frontier the only case there is a `TemporarilyBanned` is because
            // the same transaction was received before and returned
            // `InvalidTransaction::Stale`. Thus we return the same error.
            Ok(PError::TemporarilyBanned) => "nonce too low".into(),
            Ok(PError::TooLowPriority { .. }) => "replacement transaction underpriced".into(),
            Ok(PError::InvalidTransaction(inner)) => match inner {
                InvalidTransaction::Stale => "nonce too low".into(),
                InvalidTransaction::Payment => "insufficient funds for gas * price + value".into(),
                InvalidTransaction::ExhaustsResources => "gas limit reached".into(),
                InvalidTransaction::Custom(inner) => match inner.into() {
                    VError::UnknownError => "unknown error".into(),
                    VError::InvalidChainId => "invalid chain id".into(),
                    VError::InvalidSignature => "invalid sender".into(),
                    VError::GasLimitTooLow => "intrinsic gas too low".into(),
                    VError::GasLimitTooHigh => "exceeds block gas limit".into(),
                    VError::InsufficientFundsForTransfer => {
                        "insufficient funds for transfer".into()
                    }
                },
                _ => "unknown error".into(),
            },
            err @ _ => format!("submit transaction to pool failed: {:?}", err),
        }
    }
}
```

How can I allow fc_rpc::format::Formatter to be the same type as the local instance of Formatter?

Shouldn't it be possible to do this with a similar statement like this:

```rust
dyn fc_rpc::format::Formatter: Formatter,
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Geth: fc_rpc::format::Formatter` is not satisfied
   --> node/rpc/src/lib.rs:255:17
    |
255 |       io.extend_with(EthApiServer::to_delegate(EthApi::new(
    |  ____________________^
256 | |         client.clone(),
257 | |         pool.clone(),
258 | |         graph.clone(),
...   |
269 | |         fee_history_cache,
270 | |     )));
    | |______^ the trait `fc_rpc::format::Formatter` is not implemented for `Geth`
    |
note: required by a bound in `fc_rpc::EthApi`
   --> /home/filip/.cargo/git/checkouts/frontier-752fb1c28a6c675a/ea37e8f/client/rpc/src/eth.rs:65:72
    |
65  | pub struct EthApi<B: BlockT, C, P, CT, BE, H: ExHashT, A: ChainApi, F: Formatter> {
    |                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `fc_rpc::EthApi`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Geth: fc_rpc::format::Formatter` is not satisfied
   --> node/rpc/src/lib.rs:255:2
    |
255 | /     io.extend_with(EthApiServer::to_delegate(EthApi::new(
256 | |         client.clone(),
257 | |         pool.clone(),
258 | |         graph.clone(),
...   |
269 | |         fee_history_cache,
270 | |     )));
    | |_______^ the trait `fc_rpc::format::Formatter` is not implemented for `Geth`
    |
note: required by a bound in `fc_rpc::EthApi`
   --> /home/filip/.cargo/git/checkouts/frontier-752fb1c28a6c675a/ea37e8f/client/rpc/src/eth.rs:65:72
    |
65  | pub struct EthApi<B: BlockT, C, P, CT, BE, H: ExHashT, A: ChainApi, F: Formatter> {
    |                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `fc_rpc::EthApi`
```

Check out the code:
git clone -b erup-5-latest https://github.com/edgeware-network/edgeware-node

Comment: if this is still a problem for you, please open an issue on the frontier repo where you can get more specific help.